# LongListSelector Turnstile effect isn't working

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I have added WP-toolkit to my project, the pages' animation and the LLS tilt effect is working, but not the Turnstile effect. Instead of animating each list items separately, it animates the whole page at the same time. This is my xaml:

```
    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage
x:Class="SzegediMenetrend.V2.V2megallo"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DataContext="{d:DesignData V2.xaml}"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True"
toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True">
    <toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>
        <toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
            <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
                <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="BackwardIn" />
            </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
            <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
                <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="ForwardIn" />
            </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
        </toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
    </toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>
    <toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationOutTransition>
        <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition>
            <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Backward>
                <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="BackwardOut" />
            </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Backward>
            <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Forward>
                <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="ForwardOut" />
            </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Forward>
        </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition>
    </toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationOutTransition>
    <Grid  x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
            <TextBlock Text="2-ES VILLAMOS" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" toolkit:TurnstileFeatherEffect.FeatheringIndex="0" />
            <TextBlock Text="megállók" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}" toolkit:TurnstileFeatherEffect.FeatheringIndex="1" />
        </StackPanel>

        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <phone:LongListSelector toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True" x:Name="MainLongListSelector" Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectionChanged="MainLongListSelector_SelectionChanged" toolkit:TurnstileFeatherEffect.FeatheringIndex="2" >
                <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineOne}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineTwo}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

I've tried it both on simple and pivot pages, and it still don't work. What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using "regular" turnstile transition instead of feathered one. Change it to this.

```
<toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>
    <toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
        <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
            <toolkit:TurnstileFeatherTransition Mode="BackwardIn"/>
        </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
        <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
            <toolkit:TurnstileFeatherTransition Mode="ForwardIn"/>
        </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
    </toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
</toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>
<toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationOutTransition>
    <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition>
        <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Backward>
            <toolkit:TurnstileFeatherTransition Mode="BackwardOut"/>
        </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Backward>
        <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Forward>
            <toolkit:TurnstileFeatherTransition Mode="ForwardOut"/>
        </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Forward>
    </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition>
</toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationOutTransition>
```